# Is it possible to make onBackPressed only for activity but not for the fragments containg it?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have one activity and other are fragments containing it. My fragment_container is a activity. Activity is my Main Activity.I call fragmentTransaction and replace in the Activity. But when i press back hardware button it directly closes my app, so i use warning  alert dialog box. Now the problem is when i press the back button it pop up the dialog box? Is there anyway to fix this? Below is my code:

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Quit App?").setCancelable(true).setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
             finish();
        }
    }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

        }
    }).show();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.img_boy:
            cardView cardview=new cardView();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container,cardview);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            break;   
    }
}
```

}

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: In the  code above, you can clearly see that if button was click then i called fragment and replaced in the current activity. The problem is that now I click on back button it displays Alert  Dialog instead of Going back to Activity. But I need Alert Dialog in Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happening because your not modifying the `onBackPressed` correctly. First you need to get the number of fragments in the `backstack` of `FragmentManager` and take actions accordingly.

Here is the example in your case:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
        // this will get the fragments in the backstack, Replace `getFragmentManager` with `getSupportFragmentManager` if your using `v4.app.Fragment` 
    int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

    switch(count){
        case 0:
             AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setTitle("Quit App?").setCancelable(true).setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                        }
                    }).show();
            break;
        default:
            //Replace `getFragmentManager` with `getSupportFragmentManager` if your using `v4.app.Fragment` here too
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Anders, Working like charm.. But where did you learn all these stuff? I think developer.android.com/training also doesn't mention about it. You guys are so talent. I love you..

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can handle fragment back press like this example

```
handleBackPressed(view);//view is fragment layout

//setKey Listener
 private void handleBackPressed(View view)
    {
        view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        view.requestFocus();
        view.setOnKeyListener(this);
    }

//handle key listener

  @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK )
        {
           //handle your code here...
        }
    }
```